# Multiple Resource Routing In Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, url-routing

I have two unrelated models, say **Person** and **Building**. When the app receives a url like *www.mysite.com/JohnDoe/EmpireState* I would like to show properties of the Person with the name johnDoe, and the same for the building with the name EmpireState.

I'm confused as to the routing part specifically. I'm unsure if I need to create a pages controller that can return the objects from the database. How should I go about doing this?

Am hoping for something like below?

```
match ':user_name/:building_name', :controller => pages
```

Comment: If the two models are truly unrelated, you should probably not represent them as a single resource (url).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If those two are not related, you shouldn't do it that way. If they ARE related, we call that nested resources.

Example:

```
resources :projecs do
  resources :tasks
end
```

Sample URL: "/projects/12/tasks/1281"

**Edit:** 
If they are NOT related (taken from my comment):

In your BuildingsController you can fetch the parent informations too. If you use the match route in your question, you'll have params[:user_name] AND params[:building_name] available and can fetch anything you want with them...

```
Building.find_by_name(params[:building_name]) # return all Buildings based on URL param
```

Comment: Yup thanks for clarifying, I had read over the Routing guide on the rails site, but still haven't seen anything relevant to what Id like to do. It's mainly for vanity urls but I would have thought its possible.

Comment: what do you mean by "vanity urls"?

Comment: everything is possible...you want to show building's page when on second level and person's page when on first level?

Comment: nope, I'd like one page to show both the person and building. By Vanity urls I meant just have the url looking nice

Comment: In your BuildingsController you can fetch the parent informations too. If you use the match route in your question, you'll have params[:user_name] AND params[:building_name] available and can fetch anything you want with them... Building.find_by_name(params[:building_name]) will return all Buildings with the name in the URL.

Comment: Just to clairify, the two objects are NOT related, that will still work?

Comment: My last comment should work, doesn't matter if they are related or not as you do it mostly by hand.